# Jdivert java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error when ran

Tags: java

Trying to use this library, but whenever I run it. It gives me the following. I updated my pom file and thought it would be the solution, but I still receive an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Pointer
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Pointer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Here is my code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws WinDivertException {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");

        WinDivert w = new WinDivert("tcp.DstPort == 80 and tcp.PayloadLength > 0");

        w.open(); // packets will be captured from now on

        Packet packet = w.recv();  // read a single packet
        System.out.println(packet);
        w.send(packet);  // re-inject the packet into the network stack

        w.close();  // stop capturing packets
    }
}
```

And here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Glacial1.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ffalcinelli</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdivert</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Tried updating my pom file and it didn't work

Comment: It seems the jna jar is not in your classpath. How do you launch your main?

Comment: I am simply just running it, im slightly new so im not entirely sure what is meant by that

Comment: Do you type a command line to run your main? if yes, which one? or do you use a button on your IDE? in that case, what IDE are you using? how is it configured?

Comment: I'm currently using my IDE, I attempted this first on eclipse. Then On Intellij, in terms of configuration it's gonna be default